# FFMPEG:Multiple Image frames + 1 Audio =1 Video

Tags: android, audio, video, ffmpeg

I am using this library [Android-MJPEG-Video-Capture-FFMPEG](https://github.com/pvskalyan/Android-MJPEG-Video-Capture-FFMPEG?source=c)  to and getting the frames with using the camera..I am Using below FFMPEG command for this

```
String[] ffmpegCommand = {
                    "/data/data/com.mobvcasting.mjpegffmpeg/ffmpeg", "-r",
                    "" + p.getPreviewFrameRate(), "-b", "1000000",
                    "-vcodec", "mjpeg", "-i",
                    TEMPIMAGEPATH + "frame_%05d.jpg", "-i",
                    VIDEOPATH + "video.mov" };
```

Its working fine..while getting the frames i am also recording the audio.now i want to add audio to the output video..I have tried with this command but its not working..

```
String[] ffmpegCommand = {
                    "/data/data/com.mobvcasting.mjpegffmpeg/ffmpeg", "-r",
                    "" + p.getPreviewFrameRate(), "-b", "1000000",
                    "-vcodec", "mjpeg", "-acodec", "copy", "-i",
                    TEMPIMAGEPATH + "frame_%05d.jpg", "-i",
                    VIDEOPATH + "audio.mp4", VIDEOPATH + "video.mov" };
```

searched in google but no working solutions found..

QUESTION::

```
what is the correct command for combining audio and frames into video??
```

Comment: I think you should add option map before output filename, like:
    -map [0:v] -map [1:a]

Comment: "Not working" is never as useful as the actual console output.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard I have tried like this 
      "/data/data/com.mobvcasting.mjpegffmpeg/ffmpeg", "-i",
      VIDEOPATH + "audio.3gp", "-i",
      TEMPIMAGEPATH + "frame_%05d.jpg", /*
               * "-acodec", "copy ",
               * "-vcodec", "mpeg4"
               */
      "-r", "" + p.getPreviewFrameRate(),
      "-b", "1000000", "-shortest", VIDEOPATH + "video.mkv"  its giving me video but audio is not coming..i am stuck here help me please..

Comment: @ptQa i have tried with map but it saying map is not recognized

Comment: What exactly do are you trying to execute when "map is not recognized"?

Comment: trying to add multiple images and one audio file into video file..video is coming but audio is not coming

Comment: You need to show the actual, unscripted ffmpeg command and the complete ffmpeg console output. Please do not try to cram it in comments but you can update your question with this info.

Comment: Link not working. can you please fixed it.

Answer (score 6):

I found the solution after applied lot of tricks.

```
public void myFunction(ShellCallback sc, String imgPath, String audioPath, String outPath) throws IOException, InterruptedException
    {

        Log.e("MyFunction","audioPath"+audioPath);
        Log.e("MyFunction","imagePath"+imgPath);
        ArrayList<String> cmd = new ArrayList<String>();

        cmd = new ArrayList<String>();

        cmd.add(ffmpegBin);
        cmd.add("-y");
        cmd.add("-loop");
        cmd.add("1");
        cmd.add("-r");
        cmd.add("1");
        cmd.add("-i");
        cmd.add(new File(imgPath).getCanonicalPath());
        cmd.add("-i");
        cmd.add(new File(audioPath).getCanonicalPath());
        cmd.add("-acodec");
        cmd.add("aac");
        cmd.add("-vcodec");
        cmd.add("mpeg4");
        cmd.add("-s");
        cmd.add("480x320");
        cmd.add("-strict");
        cmd.add("experimental");
        cmd.add("-b:a");
        cmd.add("32k");
        cmd.add("-shortest");
        cmd.add("-f");
        cmd.add("mp4");
        cmd.add("-r");
        cmd.add("2");
        File fileOut = new File(outPath);
        cmd.add(fileOut.getCanonicalPath());

        execFFMPEG(cmd, sc);
    }
```

I hope this may help others.Thanks!

Comment: @kalyanpvs,What happend about your issue?

Comment: @ArslanAhmad, You need to be download ffmpeg library and import into eclipse.then add to the desire project. put the above function in the ffmpeg project.

Comment: Yes I have already import this library. but I think ffmpegBin is something like the variable.

Comment: String ffmpegBin = new File(Path,"ffmpeg").getAbsolutePath();
         Runtime.getRuntime().exec("chmod 700 " +ffmpegBin);



         String[]    ffmpegCommand=new String[]{
                 ffmpegBin, "-h"
             };

I think ffmpeg should be declare like this

Comment: @Kalyan, Jagdish, Arslam Ahmad, Am also having the exactly same requirement of "Multiple Image frames + 1 Audio =1 Video". and also I got video without audio. Which value i should pass to "ShellCallback sc" while calling the function? Can anyone help me to solve it? Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: From where you are getting this "execFFMPEG" method?

Answer (score 1):

From jagadish answer, i tried the command like this, this is worked for me.

> -y -i /storage/emulated/0/images.jpg -i /storage/emulated/0/rec.wav -acodec aac -vcodec mpeg4 -s 480*320 -f mp4 -r 2 /storage/emulated/0/result.mp4"

Answer (score 0):

Try with the below command it should work with multiple images 
Library - [https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java](http://Librarylink)

Here ***test$04d.png*** refers to series of images like **test0001.png, test0002.png** etc.. make sure that you have the same name image conventions for your images names

```
ffmpeg -r 1/5 -i /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Screenshots/test%04d.png -c:v libx264 -vf fps=20 -pix_fmt yuv420p /storage/emulated/0/Movies/out.mp4
```

With Music file

```
ffmpeg -r 1/5 -i /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Screenshots/test%04d.png -i /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Screenshots/music.mp3 -c:v libx264 -vf fps=20 -pix_fmt yuv420p /storage/emulated/0/Movies/out.mp4
```

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

```
   inputCode = new String[]{FileUtils.getFFmpeg(getApplicationContext()),
                "-y", "-r", "15", "-i", ImageListDirectory + "",
                "-i", Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + "MusuicFile.mp3", "-shortest",
                "-c:v", "libx264", "-pix_fmt", "yuv420p", "-c:a", "aac", Outputpath};
```

you can try this command.