# Merge .m4a files in android using ffmpeg library

Tags: android, audio, merge, ffmpeg, m4a

I have a couple of M4A (sound) files. I want to combine into a single sound file. Can this using ffmpeg library in android.

I tried this way.

```
public void myFunctionMergeAudioFiles(ShellCallback sc,List<String> mListFiles, String outPath) throws IOException, InterruptedException
    {

        ArrayList<String> cmd = new ArrayList<String>();
        cmd = new ArrayList<String>();
        cmd.add(ffmpegBin);
        cmd.add("f");
        cmd.add("concat");
        cmd.add("-i");
        for(int i=0;i<mListFiles.size();i++){
            cmd.add(new File(mListFiles.get(i)).getCanonicalPath());
        }
        cmd.add("-c");
        cmd.add("-acodec");
        cmd.add("aac");
        cmd.add("copy");
        File fileOut = new File(outPath);
        cmd.add(fileOut.getCanonicalPath());
        execFFMPEG(cmd, sc);
    }
```

My Log:-

```
01-23 15:32:17.841: D/FFMPEG(12678): /data/app-lib/com.apps.messagingapp-1/libffmpeg.so f concat -i /storage/emulated/0/MGOApp/Temp/Recording #1_0.m4a /storage/emulated/0/MGOApp/Temp/Recording #1_1.m4a /storage/emulated/0/MGOApp/Temp/Recording #1_2.m4a -c -acodec aac copy /storage/emulated/0/MGOApp/Recording #1.m4a
```

But i am not getting any error.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did u get any solutions?

Comment: Yes, I have done using ffmpeg and another example for merge image to audio is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20463719/ffmpegmultiple-image-frames-1-audio-1-video/21304505#21304505

Comment: I posted an answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20463719/ffmpegmultiple-image-frames-1-audio-1-video/21304505#21304505

Answer (score 1):

I believe you've got to create a text file and use it as your input. The text file needs to look like this:

```
file 'file1.m4a'
file 'file2.m4a'
```

Then run the following command line should be like:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i "Path\To\MyList.txt" -c copy concatOutput.m4a
```

That works for me.
You should be able to create the list text file on the fly in your code and delete it after you've run your FFMPEG command line.

More info on this [guide](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/How%20to%20concatenate%20%28join,%20merge%29%20media%20files#samecodec)

Comment: Thanks for reply @AJ29, I am using another .m4a files.